# How to initialize an array of object using a constructor with arguments?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to generate equations for a game.

I created a class for every term in the equation:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class EquationTerm
{
    public int Value { get; set; }      //random int between 1 and 9
    public int Sign { get; set; }       //1 for +, 2 for -, 3 for *, 4 for / 
    public bool IsNextTerm { get; set; }

    //default positive equationTerm 
    public EquationTerm(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Sign = 1;
        IsNextTerm = false;
    }

    public EquationTerm(int value, int sign, bool nextTerm)
    {
        Value = value;
        Sign = sign;
        IsNextTerm = nextTerm;
    }
}
```

Then I create two arrays to hold the left and right side of the equation. I want to use an InitializeArray function to generate both array using my constructors, except I can't use them since they both have parameters. 
Is there any way around this ?

```
public class EquationGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    EquationTerm[] LeftTerms;
    EquationTerm[] RightTerms;

    void Start ()
    {
        //Initialize both side with a random number of terms
        LeftTerms = InitializeArray<EquationTerm>(Random.Range (1, 6));
        RightTerms = InitializeArray<EquationTerm>(Random.Range (1, 6));
    }

    EquationTerm[] InitializeArray<EquationTerm>(int length) where EquationTerm : new()
    {
        EquationTerm[] array = new EquationTerm[length];
        array [0] = new EquationTerm (Random.Range (1, 10));
        for (int i = 1; i < length; ++i)
        {
            array[i] = new EquationTerm (Random.Range (1, 10), Random.Range (1, 5), true);
        }

        return array;
    }
```

I saw in an other post that I could Use Activator.CreateInstance so I tried writing

```
array[0] = (EquationTerm)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(EquationTerm), new object[] { EquationTerm (Random.Range (1, 10)) });
```

but it tells me that Activator does not exist.

Comment: Whats Random.Range? Is it that you wanted to create an object of Random class and call .Next(minvalue,maxvalue)?

Comment: Also, why is it a generic method when all it is going to expect is EquationTerm?

Comment: I'm using Random.Range to get a random int. For exemple, InitializeArray<EquationTerm>(Random.Range (1, 6)); is supposed to get me an array with between 1 and 5 EquationTerm objects.                                              I'm not sure to understand your second question ?

Comment: I just checked, its in UnityEngine namespace.. ok what about the second question

Comment: which method are you talking about? InitializeArray ?

Comment: yes, InitializeArray

Comment: well I don't know, I used an exemple from the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try a non-generic version:

```
public class EquationGenerator 
        {
            EquationTerm[] LeftTerms;
            EquationTerm[] RightTerms;

            void Start()
            {
                //Initialize both side with a random number of terms
                LeftTerms = InitializeArray(Random.Range(1, 6));
                RightTerms = InitializeArray(Random.Range(1, 6));
            }

            EquationTerm[] InitializeArray(int length)
            {

                EquationTerm[] array = new EquationTerm[length];
                array[0] = new EquationTerm(Random.Range(1, 10));
                for (int i = 1; i < length; ++i)
                {
                    array[i] = new EquationTerm(Random.Range(1, 10), Random.Range(1, 5), true);
                }

                return array;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please use Random.Range from UnityEngine.

Comment: as you said, just need to change 'new Random().Next(1, 10)' with : 'Random.Range(1,10)'

Comment: @singsuyash you can edit your answer to include Random.Range.